# Xcode 8: class_getProperty is Null for Core Data Category

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

I would like to check for properties with `class_getProperty` on Core Data related classes and categories.

**Structure**:

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject
@end

@interface Person (CoreDataProperties)
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@end
```

**Code**:

```
objc_property_t property = class_getProperty([Person class],
                        [@"name" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); // NULL !?
const char *propertyAttributes = property_getAttributes(property);
```

**Problem:**

Since Xcode 8 `property` is Null and `property_getAttributes()` will let the App crash.

I found older questions, but no solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arg...bad and stupid error.

I forgot to add the Categories to the target.
Sometimes it is so simple.